# Atom - linter-tidy not linting

Tags: html, atom-editor, tidy, htmltidy

I'm having an issue setting up atom for html. I installed linter for atom and linter-tidy linked from the atom linter's website. I put tidy.exe in C:/tidy/tidy.exe. In the linter-tidy settings I've tried no path to tidy, C:/tidy/tidy.exe and C:/tidy/. I have also tried disabling all of my packages except for linter, linter-tidy, and language-html. No matter what I do, it detects no errors. All it says is "No issues" at the bottom of the file.
The console says:

```
activate linter-tidy                    init.coffee:9
Window load time: 3565ms                  index.js:46
```

[image: Here is what I see, and my packages.]

What can I do to make it lint properly?

Links to linter and linter-tidy
 atom.io/packages/linter

atom.io/packages/linter-tidy

Comment: This package works for me: https://atom.io/packages/linter-htmlhint

Comment: linter-tidy isn't working for me, either. Yes, linter-htmlhint does seem to actually show lint issues, but it is [broken for XHTML5](https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-htmlhint/issues/58), which is why I wanted to try linter-tidy.